# building dinamically array for react-simple-image-slider

Tags: arrays, reactjs, slider, setstate

React simple slider needs array of images at the star and some code inside html to initiate the slider

```
const images = [
  { url: "images/1.jpg" },
  { url: "images/2.jpg" },
  { url: "images/3.jpg" },
  { url: "images/4.jpg" },
  { url: "images/5.jpg" },
  { url: "images/6.jpg" },
  { url: "images/7.jpg" },
];
```

for images array I made

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
```

maybe different way is better correct me pls.
Then I have useEffect where I fetch the data

```
 useEffect(() => {
const getData= async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`url`, {
    fetch request....
    const ImagesArray = imagesArrayfromFetch.map((image) => ({
                url: `/img/${image}`,
              }));
              console.log(ImagesArray);
              setImages(ImagesArray);
              console.log(images);
```

When I console.log ImagesArray - it gives me correctly filled array object.
console.log(images) gives me undefined. Here is an error probably
Then inside html I  build the slider object

```
const App = () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <SimpleImageSlider
            width={896}
            height={504}
            images={images}
            showBullets={true}
            showNavs={true}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

So because setImages do not put array inside images slider object creates without images.
Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have a race condition.
Setting new state must happen after resolve.
Could be done in `fetch().then( /* set state */ )`

Cleaner way would be with await/async:

```
const fetchImages = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await fetch(...);
      if (data) {
        const ImagesArray = data.images.map((image) => ({
            url: `/img/${image}`,
          }));
          console.log(ImagesArray);
          setImages(ImagesArray);
      }
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
}
useEffect(() => fetchImages(), [])
```

Comment: doing just like that but get undefined array

Comment: I've updated my question. my fetch was the same as yours, I just did not write the detailed code. But problem is somewhere else cause console.log(images) after setImages gives empty array